# Compile ANTLR4 runtime with GCC/MinGW

Tags: api, runtime, mingw, antlr4

I am trying to compile the ANTLR4 runtime sources
with GCC compiler and MinGW libraries. Is that
possible.

My development environment :
Windows 10, CodeBlocks, GCC, MinGW libraries

Compilation stops with the following error :

> error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Kind regards
Pier Tilma

Answer (score 0):

The MinGW version that comes with Code::Blocks us much too old.

Use a more up to date version of MinGW-w64.

For example the one from: https://winlibs.com/ (instructions for Code::Blocks are on the site).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sanders,

Using an up-to-date MingW version doesn't give me anymore the
*error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type*.

But now I ran into another problem :
When crosscompiling the ANTLR4 runtime sources for windows on Linux I
get the following error :
*/src/atn/ATNSimulator.cpp:17:21: error: definition of static data member ‘antlr4::atn::ATNSimulator::ERROR’ of dllimport’d class*

My configuration :
os : Ubuntu (Linux 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64),
compiler : x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (9.3 posix),
antlr4 : runtime sources 4.11.1

Regards pstilma

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).